# generated excel from SSIS but getting quote in every column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have `generated and excel from SSIS package` successfully.
But `every column` is having extra `'` (quote) mark why is it so?

[image]

My source sql table is like below

```
Name    price    address
ashu    123      pune
jkl     34       UK
```

In my `sql table` i took `all column` as `varchar(50)` datatype.
In `Excel Manager` when it is going to create table
`Excel Destination` took all column as same `varchar(50)` datatype.

And in `Data Flow` I have used `Data Conversion transformation` to prevent `unicode` conversion error.

Please advice where i need to change to get the clear columns in excel file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a **template** Excel file in which you have specified all the column types (change to Text from General) and headers you will need. Store it in a `/Template` directory and have copy it over to where you will need it from within the SSIS package.

In your SSIS package:

1. Use **Script Component** to copy Excel Template file into directory of choice.
2. Programatically change its name and store the whole filepath in a variable that will be used in your corresponding Data Flow Task.
3. Use Expression Builder for your Excel Connection Manager. Set the **ExcelFilePath** to be retrieved from your variable.

Answer (score 2):

the single quote or apostrophe is a way of entering any data (in Excel) and ensure it is treated as text so numbers with leading zeros or fractions are not interpreted by Excel as numeric or dates.

a NJ zip code for instance  07456 would be interpreted as 7456 but by entering it as '07456 it keeps its leading zero (please note that numbers in your example are left aligned, like text is)

I guess SSIS is adding the quotes because your data is of VARCHAR type

Comment: How do I prevent it because i want to use this excel file further which may could be wrong input file.
please advice?

Answer (score 1):

First, define the field types for your excel destination in SSIS, any non-text fields will format properly without the '.  Then, add a derived column transformation between your source and destination, and use a replace statement for any text columns.
Should be:

```
(REPLACE(Column1, "'","")
```

Answer (score 0):

This caused me major problems! So I completed the following:
You can change the excel version to 'Microsoft Excel 4.0' within the excel connection manager in your SSIS package.
Then within excel follow Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > File Block Settings > Untick the 'Open' checkbox for 'Excel 4 workbooks' and 'sheets'.

Answer (score 0):

It is a particular problem when using the Excel destination, at least with older versions of SSIS anyway. To answer the why question, there is this in the Microsoft documentation:

> The following behaviors of the Jet provider that is included with the Excel driver can lead to unexpected results when saving data to an Excel destination.

> **Saving text data.** When the Excel driver saves text data values to an Excel destination, *the driver precedes the text in each cell with the single quote character (') to ensure that the saved values will be interpreted as text values*. If you have or develop other applications that read or process the saved data, you may need to include special handling for the single quote character that precedes each text value.

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms137643(v=sql.105)