# SSIS : Remove ' from headers

Tags: ssis

I am dynamicly creating excel sheet in SSIS. Everything works as excepted, except when it creates the header row it has a `'` in front of all the columns. The expression I am using evaluates to :

```
CREATE TABLE `SheetACCT` (
    `APP` LongText,
    `ACCT` LongText,
    `ACCTSTATUS` LongText
)
```

The sheet name does not have a quote , but all the headers have a single quote in the front so : 
'APP | 'ACCT | 'ACCTSTATUS

I am wondering how I can remove this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705342/generated-excel-from-ssis-but-getting-quote-in-every-column

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I can't make a template because I am creating the sheets dynamically and the columns can change at any point. I think what I will have to do is script out something to loop through each workbook, then through each sheet, and change the data type row 1. Thanks though

Comment: Just write to a file the data. I do not see a need in creating Excel via SQL