# SSIS Excel Destination exporting data with leading apostrophe

Tags: excel, ssis

i cant believe i am struggling with this so much. you would think that since SSIS and Excel are both Mirosoft products they would interact seamlessly...

I have some data in a SQL Server table which i want to export to Excel. None of the data in any of the columns in SQL server have a leading apostrophe. So the solution is not use REPLACE.

Once I create an empty file through the Excel Destination task I open the file and format the columns to what I need them to be save and close the file. I run the package when i open the file all columns are preceded with a ' e.g. 'WA or '1234. If i recreate the file again following the procedure above and i format the columns and enter data into the first row, save the file and rerun the package, the data in the excel file is inserted correctly without any leading '.

How do i remove the leading apostrophe without having to insert a template row?

What is the best practice solution for this? The data is going to be uploaded into another database at another company and they dont want the leading apostrophe's.

Comment: Yes it's suprising how difficult integration is between the tools. It's due partially to the 'not quite a table, not quite a schema' nature of excel but also there are some long standing truly terrible bugs which should have been fixed long ago. My first suggestion, without knowng the background, is to export to tab separated text file instead and open that in excel. It will again perform it's own peculiar butchery on the data during this process but it might be closer to what you need.

Comment: Nick, we were supplying the data as .csv for a few months. They have changed the process on their side and now require the output to be excel.

Comment: Then they're in for a world of pain because if they are importing their data, there are just as many gotchas on the import side. The only data transfer format worse than CSV is XLS.... anyway I"m sure there is a solution, I'll have a google

Comment: The behaviour you describe has something to so with the excel driver incorrectly guessing data types. (which will also be an issue on the import side). What happens if you pre-format all columns as "General"? Does this shed any light on it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705342/generated-excel-from-ssis-but-getting-quote-in-every-column

Comment: If they are moving to excel because of problems with CSV then they are going the wrong way. They should be using tab seperated or somehting equally innocuous like a pipe ( | )  or squiggle ( ~ )

Comment: Depending on your end user, you can always just export a tab seperated file, rename to .xlsx and see if they notice ;)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid as I have said above, i have formatted the excel document. I have made the number columns numbers and the text column text. I have saved the file with the formatting. When i run the process on the templated file it puts adds '. If i formate the file like i want it AND add a row with fake data in the format i want it, save the template file and rerun the package it populates the data correctly but then the problem is i have a row of junk data. I saw a post saying you need to update a registry entry to 0 or something. No sure if they will allow that at work or not.

Comment: What I said was what happens if you pre-format all columns as "General"? Anyway the registry thing you're referring to is IMEX. See the sample string in this article: https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it Not sure if it'll fix but worth a try.

Comment: What version is the Excel document that you're exporting to?